# Build Linux Kernel module with warning i2c_register_board_info undefined

Tags: module, linux-kernel, driver

I follow an example in [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices) to write an i2c driver but unfortunately when i compile i got this warning

> WARNING: "i2c_register_board_info" [/home/pi/builddriver/samplei2c/pn535.ko] undefined!

Although compile with 1 warning and no error, I cannot insmod module. this is error when insmod

> insmod: ERROR: could not insert module pn535.ko: Invalid module format

My question is how to solve the warning above?, I think it make .ko file to be invalid. Here is my source code on 
[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rwKH9MY5)

thank for your help!

Comment: Function `i2c_register_board_info` **isn't exported** (with `EXPORT_SYMBOL`) for kernel modules. Only code **compiled into the kernel** may use such functions. As far as I understand from [its description](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-boardinfo.c#L59), the function is intended to use by *boards developers*.

Comment: Your problem is you are mixing two things in one driver, i.e. driver itself which can be a module and platform (legacy!) code, which can't. You have to drop platform code for ACPI or device tree resource provider, or as a last resort to split it out to another compile unit.

Comment: I removed i2c_register_board_info then I can build driver to module (.ko) without warring and can insmod by adding these function in init function called by module_init:
...
adapter = i2c_get_adapter(CONFIG_I2C_BUS);
...
client = i2c_new_device(adapter, &i2c_pn535_sample_devs);
...
not sure if it is good or bad. because when i remove driver (rmmod), driver does not release device and can not insmod again, I have to reboot device to insmod agian.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible in a kernel module simply because the function `i2c_register_board_info` is not exported from the kernel source tree to the kernel modules (built using `obj-m targets`). You can achieve this by building your driver within the kernel source tree using (`obj-y targets`).

Comment: Non-exported symbols cannot be used in any **kernel module** (`obj-m` targets in the Makefile), whether it is built outside a source tree or inside it. Only things compiled into the kernel (`obj-y` targets) may use this functionality.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. I didn't mean module indicated by 'm' in the config file.

Comment: See my comment above, your answer is not comprehensive, you may do better!