# i2c_register_board_info symbol is undefined

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, i2c

I am trying to write a kernel module for a BeagleBone Black that would communicate with my custom I2C slave device. I tried following several kernel module development tutorials, they all seem incomplete at some point, or assume that I know something I clearly don't... My current problem now is that the Makefile doesnt see the `i2c_register_board_info` symbol. I am writing this driver as a separate module, its not compiled during kernel compilation. Also, I have enabled the I2C tools when building using buildroot. Using the I2C tools I am able to detect and interface with my device. My Makefile looks as follows:

```
MODULE_NAME = PowerManagerDriver

PWD := $(shell pwd)
SRC_DIR = user_files
BUILD_DIR = build
BUILD_EXT = *.o .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c *.order *.symvers *.dwo

SRCS = $(SRC_DIR)/main.c $(SRC_DIR)/pmd_i2c.c 
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

obj-m += $(MODULE_NAME).o 
$(MODULE_NAME)-y = $(OBJS)

KERNELDIR ?= /home/lukasz/brl/Machine/beaglebone/build/linux-a75d8e93056181d512f6c818e8627bd4554aaf92

all: default

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
    mv $(SRC_DIR)/*.o $(BUILD_DIR)/
    mv $(BUILD_EXT) $(BUILD_DIR)/ &> /dev/null

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)/*
    rm -rf $(BUILD_EXT)
```

*`make`* output:

```
13:45:33 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project PowerManagerDriver ****
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf- -j6 all 
make -C /home/lukasz/brl/Machine/beaglebone/build/linux-a75d8e93056181d512f6c818e8627bd4554aaf92 M=/home/lukasz/eclipse-workspace/PowerManagerDriver modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lukasz/brl/Machine/beaglebone/build/linux-a75d8e93056181d512f6c818e8627bd4554aaf92'
  CC [M]  /home/lukasz/eclipse-workspace/PowerManagerDriver/user_files/main.o
  CC [M]  /home/lukasz/eclipse-workspace/PowerManagerDriver/user_files/pmd_i2c.o
/home/lukasz/eclipse-workspace/PowerManagerDriver/user_files/pmd_i2c.c:99:26: warning: ‘pdm_i2cClient’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static struct i2c_client pdm_i2cClient = { 0 };
                          ^
  LD [M]  /home/lukasz/eclipse-workspace/PowerManagerDriver/PowerManagerDriver.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "i2c_register_board_info" [/home/lukasz/eclipse-workspace/PowerManagerDriver/PowerManagerDriver.ko] undefined!
  CC      /home/lukasz/eclipse-workspace/PowerManagerDriver/PowerManagerDriver.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/lukasz/eclipse-workspace/PowerManagerDriver/PowerManagerDriver.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lukasz/brl/Machine/beaglebone/build/linux-a75d8e93056181d512f6c818e8627bd4554aaf92'
mv user_files/*.o build/
mv *.o .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c *.order *.symvers *.dwo build/ &> /dev/null

13:45:35 Build Finished. 0 errors, 1 warnings. (took 1s.394ms)
```

So far I have only few functions for I2C interfacing:

```
static int pdm_i2cProbe(struct i2c_client* client,
                        const struct i2c_device_id* id)
{
    PMD_ASSERT(client);
    PMD_ASSERT(id);

    return 0;
}

static struct i2c_driver pdm_i2cDriver =
{
    .driver =
    {
        .name = "pdm-driver",
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    },

    .probe = pdm_i2cProbe,
};

static struct i2c_board_info pdm_i2cBoardInfo[] =
{
    {
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("pdm-driver", 0x30),
        .irq = 69,
    },
};

/**
 * @brief   Initializes the I2C module.
 * @param   busNr: The I2C peripheral number on which the device is connected.
 * @return  \ref e_pdmStatus_OK on succesfull init.
 */
pmdStatus_t pdm_i2cInit(const unsigned int busNr)
{
    if (i2c_register_board_info((int)busNr, pdm_i2cBoardInfo,
            ARRAY_SIZE(pdm_i2cBoardInfo)))
        return e_pmdStatus_BADPARAM;

    if (i2c_add_driver(&pdm_i2cDriver))
        return e_pmdStatus_EXE;

    return e_pmdStatus_OK;
}
```

At this point even though I dont probe anything, as the probe function is empty, I was hoping to at least load the module correctly. I dont even get to the testing phase since the `i2c_register_board_info` is not found. My .config file for when building the kernel consists of those lines:

```
# I2C support
#
CONFIG_I2C=y
CONFIG_I2C_BOARDINFO=y
CONFIG_I2C_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_I2C_CHARDEV=y
# CONFIG_I2C_MUX is not set
CONFIG_I2C_HELPER_AUTO=y
```

I have found this topic previously [i2c registering macro not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195032/i2c-registering-macro-not-found) but I can't get anything out of it.

When trying to load the module with insmod as requested:

```
# uname -a
Linux buildroot 4.9.59 #1 SMP Fri Oct 5 11:55:54 CEST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
# insmod PowerManagerDriver.ko
[   39.438108] PowerManagerDriver: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   39.445800] PowerManagerDriver: Unknown symbol i2c_register_board_info (err 0)
[   39.455743] PowerManagerDriver: Unknown symbol i2c_register_board_info (err 0)
insmod: can't insert 'PowerManagerDriver.ko': unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter
#
```

Comment: I was going to point you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23195032) "duplicate" - but you already found it yourself ... and it it doesn't give any conclusive answers.  Look [here](https://stackoverrun.com/de/q/11810919).  It's in German ... but it *might* give you the answer you're looking for.  ALSO: since it's a "warning" ... you might be able to load and run your .ko anway.  Please post back what you learn!

Comment: Hi, will check it out, thank you. I tried loading the module and I get the same message about the missing symbol.

Comment: Q: Got it working?  Also: look [here](http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/beaglebone-an-i2c-tutorial-interfacing-to-a-bma180-accelerometer/): git clone git://github.com/derekmolloy/beaglebone.  It might give some useful tips about configuring your toolchain... Just a thought...

Comment: @paulsm4 Hi, not yet. If I understiid everything correctly, it seems like I wont be able to see this symbol while compiling my driver as an external module... I need to compile it during the kernel compilation with buildroot. Unfortunetally, I havent figured out how to do it yet. As for Derek Molloys tutoriala, I was followinf them so far, very helpfull.

Comment: I'm still wondering if this is a "blocker" (you absolutely can't load or run your kernel until you resolve it), or merely a "warning".  Does your kernel (or your toolchain/build environment) absolutely need to have i2c_register_board_info before you can use your .ko?  I don't know :(

Comment: Yes, this is a blocker. The module wont run at insmod moment :/

Comment: Q: Please copy/paste the `insmod` command and the exact error text into your post.  Please add `uname-a` as well.

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Build Linux Kernel module with warning i2c\_register\_board\_info undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945663/build-linux-kernel-module-with-warning-i2c-register-board-info-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hardware is 'guaranteed' to be there, you do not need to define the device imperatively. You can use device tree (dtb) to declare the existence of your slave at a particular address on a particular bus, provide params to your driver etc. So your module never needs to do the register board info thing.

This is explained in the docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/instantiating-devices

In other words you *should* be able to write a driver for your slave device as a kernel module using only open firmware (`of`) hooks and a populated device tree (dtb).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Could you only elaborate more of what is this `of` api you mentioned?

Comment: @Bremen I mean the Linux kernel hooks to register your driver with the OpenFirmware (of) subsystem. Take a look at this [UIO driver](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/uio/uio_pdrv_genirq.c?h=v5.0-rc2) and find the `#ifdef CONFIG_OF` section. This is what lets the kernel know about how to apply devicetree (DTB) instructions to load & configure your driver. You will need to modify this to suit your hardware use case.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it sounds like this is a duplicate of [Build Linux Kernel module with warning i2c_register_board_info undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945663/build-linux-kernel-module-with-warning-i2c-register-board-info-undefined).

PROBLEM:

```
# insmod PowerManagerDriver.ko
[   39.438108] PowerManagerDriver: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   39.445800] PowerManagerDriver: Unknown symbol i2c_register_board_info (err 0)
[   39.455743] PowerManagerDriver: Unknown symbol i2c_register_board_info (err 0)
insmod: can't insert 'PowerManagerDriver.ko': unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter
```

CAUSE:

> [Build Linux Kernel module with warning i2c_register_board_info undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945663/build-linux-kernel-module-with-warning-i2c-register-board-info-undefined)
>
> Function i2c_register_board_info isn't exported (with EXPORT_SYMBOL)
>   for kernel modules. Only code compiled into the kernel may use such
>   functions. As far as I understand from its description, the function
>   is intended to use by boards developers
>
> Your problem is you are mixing two things in one driver, i.e. driver
>   itself which can be a module and platform (legacy!) code, which can't.
>   You have to drop platform code for ACPI or device tree resource
>   provider, or as a last resort to split it out to another compile unit.

WORKAROUND:

> I removed i2c_register_board_info then I can build driver to module
>   (.ko) without warning and can insmod by adding these function in init
>   function called by module_init:
>
> ```
> ... 
> adapter = i2c_get_adapter(CONFIG_I2C_BUS); 
> ... 
> client = i2c_new_device(adapter, &i2c_pn535_sample_devs); 
> ...
> ```
>
> not sure if it is good or bad. because when i remove driver (rmmod),
>   driver does not release device and can not insmod again, I have to
>   reboot device to insmod again

Please feel free to add (and accept!) your own response if you find a different - or better - solution.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help :(